# Common strings between two sequences

Tags: python, random, sequence, percentile

I have two questions related to the same topic. I run a simulation of 16000 sequences of 100 elements without repetitions with numbers between 1-4, for example: 124232143214223142314...

These simulations were done to see what was the longest sequence in common between the sequences randomly generated and the pre-defined sequence. Participants were also asked to do this, to generate the sequence they had previously learned without awareness.

I want to find all the triplets in common between both sequences. 
So if we have sequence A: 12342134213421313242... and sequence B: 21342134123214. It would have to count all the triplets in common 
including repetitions: 213, 134, 342, 213, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```py
import itertools

x = "12342134213421313242123"
y = "213421341232123"
m = ["1","2","3","4"]

#dict of triplet vs [no of repetitions in x, in y]
z={k: [x.count(k), y.count(k)] for k in ["".join(el) for el in [a+b+c for a in m for b in m for c in m if a!=b and b!=c and a!=c]]}
#total number of common triplets:
z_no = sum([x.count(k) if x.count(k)>0 and y.count(k)>0 else 0 for k in ["".join(el) for el in [a+b+c for a in m for b in m for c in m if a!=b and b!=c and a!=c]]])
#broken down by triplet
z_final = {k: v[0] for k,v in z.items() if v[0]>0 and v[1]>0}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but z_no is equal to 2 which does not correspond to the expected answer. There are a lot more triplets in common between the two sequences.

Comment: does the triplet have to have 3 unique numbers, or e.g. "444" is ok. I edited it, so it assumes it's ok to have numbers repeated within single triplet

Comment: You cannot have consecutive repetitions. What I meant by repetitions is that in x the 123 triplet occurs twice, so in the total amount of common triplets it should be counted twice.

Comment: ah, ok, so we take triplets from shorter string, and see how many times it appears in the longer one ? (on my example y, and x respectively) ?

Comment: Yes, so we would be looking for 213, 134, 342, 213... and so on.

Comment: gotcha, now is better ? (14 is the number for the total sum)

Comment: You are a freaking life saver! Would never be able to come up with this!

Comment: no worries :) Could you upvote, and mark as an answer, if it works